# Editable, grid table in WPF that alows to change the cell appearance

Tags: wpf, cell

In my application I need to show a table. The table data will be provided by me and then the user will be allowed to change it.
When the user changes a cell data, I need to change the foreground color of the cell to blue.
If the data inserted by the user is invalid, I need to change the foreground to red.

I tried to use DataGrid, but then if I don’t set ItemSource, I can control the cell appearance, but the user can’t edit its data. If I set the ItemSource, the user can edit the data, but I have no way to change the cell.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? Besides this I need a very simple table.

Comment: You need to learn MVVM. You can perfectly do this with the `DataGrid`, but not manipulating the UI elements in procedural code, but by the use of a proper ViewModel and proper `DataTemplates`.

Comment: @HighCore is right, besides there are so many examples here, I even posted quite a few. Retyping to just give you yet another example is almost a waste of time and too boring. I highly encourage you to search better and look for CellTemplate / CellEditingTemplate, DataGrid Bindings, Triggers, Background color etc.. Then when you face a specific problem, the ask